# error cannot convert value of type `Void` to expected argument type `() -> Void` UIAlertController

Tags: swift, uialertcontroller

Very often I have to show an alert to the user and I find myself writing the same code over and over again, so I built a convenience method.

When `self.convenience.showAlertToUser()` is called in `viewDidLoad` I get error for argument `doThisAction` *cannot convert value of type `Void` to expected argument type `() -> Void`*. I don't understand why, because I pass in an argument of that type. Also, I don't know if I am creating a retain cycle, so I would appreciate your help.

```
class ConvenienceMethods {

   func showAlertToUser(alertMessage: String = "",actionOkTitle:String, actionCancelTitle:String, controller: UIViewController, cancelAction: Bool, doAction: @escaping (() -> Void)) {

    let customAlert = UIAlertController(title: "", message: alertMessage, preferredStyle: .alert)
    let actionCancel = UIAlertAction(title: actionCancelTitle, style: .cancel, handler: nil)
    let actionOk =  UIAlertAction(title: actionOkTitle, style: .default, handler: { (action: UIAlertAction) in
        doAction()
    })

    if cancelAction == true {
        customAlert.addAction(actionCancel)
    }
        customAlert.addAction(actionOk)
        controller.present(customAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
  }
}


  class ManageFeedbackTableViewController {
       let convenience = ConvenienceMethods()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
      let doThisAction = self.segueWith(id: "segueID")
       self.convenience.showAlertToUser(alertMessage: "someMessage", actionOkTitle: "OK", actionCancelTitle: "No", controller: self, cancelAction: false, doAction: doThisAction)
}

    //perform an action
     func segueWith(id: String) -> Void{
     self.performSegue(withIdentifier: id, sender: self)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are to passing a reference to the function but the result itself.

Replace 
`let doThisAction = self.segueWith(id: "segueID")`

By :

`let doThisAction = { self.segueWith(id: "segueID") }`

Comment: the error is gone. Could you please point me to some resources where I can learn more about this? I still can't wrap my head around this, how it actually works. Also, please remove the `^` character from your answer

Comment: The `^` is required to declare a block. You can have a look to https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Blocks/Articles/bxDeclaringCreating.html

Comment: if I use `^` it returns error `'^' is not prefix unary operator`

Comment: The question is about Swift. The caret `^` and the linked article is related to Objective-C.

Answer (score 1):

@bibscy, 
doThisAction is a closure to which we can assign a block of code within "{ }" as follows:- 
 let doThisAction = { self.segueWith(id: "segueID") } which will work.